# git merge the current branch as second parent

Tags: git, merge

When a merge has conflicts I back out and redo the merge with a temporary branch such that I'm merging my feature branch into the upstream branch.

This makes it simplier to see the merge diff when there are conflicts. During the merge a `git status` or `git diff` contain my feature branch changes vs. the many changes that have happened upstream.

Can I simplify these commands, hopefully to a single git command then a commit?:

```
# prepare a place to do the merge:
git checkout -b my-feature-merged-into-master origin/master
git merge my-feature
# If there are conflicts, git status should show results similar to
# git diff origin/master...my-feature
git commit
git branch -D my-feature
git branch --move my-feature-merged-into-master my-feature
```

Answer (score 0):

You start with `my-feature` branch and you end with `my-feature` branch but augmented with the upstream changes.  So clearly the easiest way, in terms of minimal Git commands, is:

```
git merge origin/master
```

If there are no conflicts, you are done.  If there are conflicts, then you will want to examine them all, one by one, and the effort involved in the examination will be much more than generating the diff.  Overall, thus, a win for the above command.

Comment: Thanks, but this merges origin/master as the second parent. git status, git diff, will show comparisons of bringing in all changes of origin/master into the my-feature branch (git diff my-feature...origin/master). The intent of the question is to instead show my-feature coming into origin/master (git diff origin/master...my-feature).